# DKIM error - no key

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dkim

Im using PowerMTA and trying to get dkim to work. Im using godaddy DNS. Gmail is giving me :

```
dkim=neutral (no key for signature) header.i=@
```

same thing with yahoo: permerror(no key)

dig output:

```
 dig +short txt dkim._domainkey.gamerbasecamp.com
"v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC3jyMaBlYI9QFs162gU+fI3Yul1gBsO6PUaGRctgdvpduywJQ9vrs3v582ZypCfB9WVndmtr1QaJ33yMrqHe+GHnwCh0XJT+9NrOnkMuEynqPoG6dZXd7ZqigXuy2pGd9eGAIin02LkG0xKrV3LMHkpp+regxBNOYKf5GDP3hNYwIDAQAB\;"
```

email to  check-auth@verifier.port25.com says:

```
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (key "dkim._domainkey.gamerbasecamp.info" doesn't exist)
```

This happened after I changed the domain of the SMTP server. I have another server with exactly the same setup and DKIM is pass.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup a `TXT` record for `dkim._domainkey.gamerbasecamp.com`, while you are doing test from `dkim._domainkey.gamerbasecamp.info`.

Comment: I suggest to try to format your sentences, look how I did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send right selector header `header.s=dkim`,

The most important thing is: selector indicates your DomainKeys/DKIM public key location. For example: if your domain selector is: "s1024", your public key record will be "s1024._domainkey.yourdomain.com"; if your domain selector is: "mta1", your public key record will be "mta1._domainkey.yourdomain.com".

Example of the right dkim header for yourdomain.com with "s1024" selector:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@yourdomain.com header.s=s1024 header.b=Nj1yIIn0
```

https://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/doc/html/selector.htm